# Image between two div with same text

Tags: image, html, layout, multiple-columns

I should build this layout

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBL5L.jpg)

but after various tests, I don't understand how place the image.
The text continues from one div to another. I've think to use the column CSS3 property but I think it's not the better solution.
How can I implement this layout?

Thanks in advice.

EDIT:

This is the HTML and CSS code of the last test:

```
.span11{
   width: 90%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-gap: 20pt;  
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap: 20pt;
   column-count: 2;
   column-gap: 20pt;    
}
#foto{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 50px;    
}

 <div class="span11">
    <div id="foto">
        <img src="http://fpoimg.com/600x400?text=Preview" >
    </div>                     
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in dui ellus.Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in dui tellus. Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in dui tellus. Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in dui tellus. Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in dui tellus. Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in  tellus. Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in dui tellus. Pellentesque ac mi neque. Nulla ultricies nulla diam. Nulla luctus risus a ante varius euismod. Fusce viverra molestie enim, malesuada condimentum est consectetur id. Vestibulum laoreet libero vitae metus cursus, a auctor tellus tempor. Suspendisse lacinia tempus metus et lobortis. Suspendisse nec sapien eleifend, viverra lacus ut, pulvinar quam.
    </div>
```

This is Jsfiddle of the last test:

http://jsfiddle.net/DVwws/

Comment: Could you please show some examples of what you tried? SO users are here to help and not write a bunch of code for others. Also source-code makes a question specific, so we can give you a specific answer.

Comment: I edit the question and I add the HTML and CSS code. I hope it is more complete.

Comment: Very good question; after some thorough research I'm not able to find any good close examples. There are some long ugly cheap tricks that could make the page appear to "work"; but there is no fully supported built-in code for that. The current text-wrap methods usually rely on float; but that cannot help the issue in your case because you would have two text fields that are wrapped around one image. There are examples where one text-field can be wrapped around multiple images; but not multiple text-fields around one image. So maybe there is a cheat, but no standard working method.

Comment: Also Phil, if you are willing to accept a solution that can get you a desired result (even if it is totally unconventional and I wouldn't professionally suggest it) I think I can provide one. Just in this circumstance where there is no built-in tools within CSS; I think cheap tricks are the only way to accomplish it.

Comment: My friend give me this two links:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html

http://css-tricks.com/float-center/

But in the first case flow-into/flow-from doesn't work in all browser, while the second link put the image at the top of the text.
Maybe I should try to merge both method. What do you think?

Thanks for the answer and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the example you found [here](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/) I was able to edit the source code and eventually create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmA3v/3/) with your desired result.

General guide to accomplish this:

1. Create two side-by-side divs filled with text
2. Use the "Content" CSS property to create "holes" in your paragraphs where they are desired with `content: ""; width: 125px; height: 250px;`.
3. Use absolute positioning to place an image within that "hole" you created.

This image should assist in understanding the placing concept: (Just imagine the green-section as being the hole and centered vertically)
[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS from the JSFiddle I made:

```
<style>
  #page-wrap { width: 100%; margin: 80px auto; position: relative; }
  #logo { position: absolute; top: 125px; left: 50%; margin-left: -125px; }
  .left, .right { width: 49%; text-align: justify}
  .left { float:left; }
  .right { float:right; }
  #l, #r { width: 100%; position: relative;}
  #l { float: left;  text-align: justify}
  #r { float: right; text-align: justify}   
  #l:before, #r:before { content: ""; width: 150px; height: 250px; vertical-align:-50%;}
  #l:before { float: right;}
  #r:before { float: left; }
</style>
```

AND

```
    <div id="page-wrap">

        <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/250" id="logo">

<div class="left">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. <div id="l">Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metuPellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt conum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursusdiment faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. </div>Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
        </div>

        <div class="right">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. <div id="r">Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. </div>Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
        </div>

    </div>
```

Also since you said you were loading your text dynamically from a data-base here is an easy way to calculate it's length and break it into two equal chunks.

```
<?php
//some SQL Queries setting $str
$len = strlen($str);
$part1 = substr($str, $len/2); 
$part2 = substr($str, $len/2+1,$len);
// Insert $part1 & $part2 text chunks into each div. 
?>
```

NOTE: Due to the exact cut, if that character number is in the middle of a word that word will be cut into two parts. There are resources to easily figure out how to cut on the next space; but that does not pertain to this specific question.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try to implement this solution.. However this solution had two text while I have one text in two paragraphs.. I hope to resolve my problem anyway!

Comment: @PhilWeb No problem, and having one text shouldn't be an issue; just figure out where the half-way point is (or where you want it to start on the right side) and cut-paste that into the other section.

Comment: In fact in a solution I think to cut, with PHP functions, in halve the text and place it within the divs. Maybe it's the right way to solve the problem.. :)

Comment: Maybe I've found the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/AmA3v/3/

However the text is from a table on a database, so I don't know its lenght. Maybe I should include CSS in the page and calcolate the values of the styles by the lenght of the text.. Right?

Comment: @PhilWeb I didn't know you were loading your text dynamically but if so then absolutely that would be a good idea.

Comment: Because this layout is used in a page of a product and the informations (text, photo or video - blue part) comes from database. ;)